# Store a subquery in a variable or something

Tags: t-sql

I've this query below, my need is that I want to do the substraction between 2 columns: `S` and `M&L`.
The problem is that `S` and `M&L` are a subqueries ... I've tried to store those subqueries on a variable, but it's not working ...

```
SELECT 
[STORE] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE ,
[SELLER] = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE,

(SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO)

FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET4 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET4.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL4 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL4.GCL_COMMERCIAL 

WHERE

AND ET4.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
AND GCL4.GCL_LIBELLE = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
AND GP_TOTALTTC < 200

) S,

(SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO)

FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET4 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET4.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL4 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL4.GCL_COMMERCIAL 

WHERE 

AND ET4.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
AND GCL4.GCL_LIBELLE = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
AND GP_TOTALTTC > 200
) 'M&L'

FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL5 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL5.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
WHERE 

GL_DATEPIECE = '2019-02-28'

GROUP BY
ET2.ET_LIBELLE,
GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
```

Comment: Also, please prefix each column with the table it belongs to. It may be evident to you where the columns are coming from, but it's not for the rest of us.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want to do and the appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Microsoft SQL, then one way to do this would be to use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I don't have any test data, so I'm just reposting your query (there are issues with the `WHERE` clauses that need to be addressed):

```
WITH cteData AS
(
    SELECT  [STORE] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE 
            , [SELLER] = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
            , (
                SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO)
                FROM    GCLIGNEARTDIM
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET4 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET4.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL4 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL4.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
                WHERE   ET4.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
                        AND GCL4.GCL_LIBELLE = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
                        AND GP_TOTALTTC < 200
            ) S
            , (
                SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO)
                FROM    GCLIGNEARTDIM
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET4 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET4.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL4 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL4.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
                WHERE   ET4.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
                        AND GCL4.GCL_LIBELLE = GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
                        AND GP_TOTALTTC > 200
            ) 'M&L'
    FROM    GCLIGNEARTDIM
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL5 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL5.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
    WHERE   GL_DATEPIECE = '2019-02-28'
    GROUP BY ET2.ET_LIBELLE, GCL5.GCL_LIBELLE
)
SELECT  *
        , ([S] - [M&L]) AS [S minus M&L]
FROM    cteData
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What a solution !! U SAVED MY LIFE